# How to Create your own print Function PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way we can create our own print function in PHP so when using it we can do the following

```
my_print_function "My Content";
```

rather than

```
my_print_function("My Content");
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just to save the two keystrokes for writing the parenthesis in function calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. The ones without brackets (like echo, and include) are **language constructs**, which you can't make in your own code. Could probably do it by making a PHP extension in C, but it's not possible in pure PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP syntax requires parenthesis for custom functions. `print`, `echo` etc. are language constructs, meaning they're special cases hardcoded into the PHP engine. You'll have to extend the core PHP engine if you want to create something similar.